# Gutenberg Block Editor - Create block with dynamic content

Tags: custom-taxonomy, javascript, block-editor

The official [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-create-block/) has a example of creating a demo block.

The example has an `edit.js` and `save.js` for creating an editor view and front end view.

Assuming I want to create a block that prints a list of custom taxonomies. I can create the block, the content will save and display on the front end.

The issue is that if an item will be added to that custom taxonomies, it won't be shown unless I remove the block and add it back again because the custom taxonomy list is saved as part of the block content.

If we look how the default WordPress categories block works `wp-content/blocks/categories.php`, seems like it's not rendered from React at all. In the post only something like this is saved `<!-- wp:categories {"displayAsDropdown":true} /-->`, and the content is rendered dynamically from php, including the js "onChange" function.

I need to add some logic and functionality with React to my custom block, so creating a block the same way the core categories block is won't work for me.

How can I print a block with dynamic content in a similar way the core categories work, but with React JS similar to the [todo demo block](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-create-block/)?

The docs has [dynamic block](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/block-tutorial/creating-dynamic-blocks/) which is rendered it PHP. I would like to render the dynamic block with React.

Comment: Are you sure it won't work? What kind of logic and functionality you plan to add? Have you checked [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-edit-save/#save)?

Comment: It works, but the list will be hard coded in the content. Meaning if the list will be updated, the post wont be updated

Comment: I was actually asking why don't you just use the dynamic block, hence I asked about the logic and functionality - perhaps you can just use the block attributes for that and let PHP do the actual thing?

Comment: "I would like to render the dynamic block with React." - if you mean the `edit` function, then you can use the REST API to fetch the custom taxonomies and render it to the client. I.e. Render the same output that would be rendered by the PHP callback. And there's an example [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/block-tutorial/creating-dynamic-blocks/) - the `edit` function renders one post, and so does the PHP callback.